# How to achieve Pinch Zoom & Swipe on SKCanvasView?

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I am developing image viewer using xamarin forms. My source image is of infinite size which is way bigger then my viewport. So I am using SKCanvasView control to draw part by part so that I should swipe through the Image.

I am able to get Touch point through Touch event which is available on SKCanvasView. Here, I am able to detect double tap. Swipe and Panning.

I am not able to decide on when I swipe up/down how much image need to shift up/down?

Initially, I have tried placing SKCanvasView on top of ScrollView control and using scroll position value I was painting SKCanvas. Here scrolling and printing works perfect. But here Pinch zoom was not working as Pinch gesture event was not firing instead it was scrolling.

Answer (score 7):

I did something similar to this sometime back for one of my friends for SKCanvas even though I have personally never used Skia.

In any case, it has Pinch, Pan and Tap zoom events feel free to make any changes as per your needs:

```
 public class CustomSKCanvas : SKCanvasView
{
    private const double MIN_SCALE = 1;
    private const double MAX_SCALE = 4;
    private const double OVERSHOOT = 0.15;
    private double StartScale, LastScale;
    private double StartX, StartY;

    public CustomSKCanvas()
    {
        var pinch = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
        pinch.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(pinch);

        var pan = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        pan.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(pan);

        var tap = new TapGestureRecognizer { NumberOfTapsRequired = 2 };
        tap.Tapped += OnTapped;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);

        Scale = MIN_SCALE;
        TranslationX = TranslationY = 0;
        AnchorX = AnchorY = 0;
    }

    protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        Scale = MIN_SCALE;
        TranslationX = TranslationY = 0;
        AnchorX = AnchorY = 0;
        return base.OnMeasure(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
    }

    private void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Scale > MIN_SCALE)
        {
            this.ScaleTo(MIN_SCALE, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
            this.TranslateTo(0, 0, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
        }
        else
        {
            AnchorX = AnchorY = 0.5; //TODO tapped position
            this.ScaleTo(MAX_SCALE, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
        }
    }

    private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                StartX = (1 - AnchorX) * Width;
                StartY = (1 - AnchorY) * Height;
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                AnchorX = Clamp(1 - (StartX + e.TotalX) / Width, 0, 1);
                AnchorY = Clamp(1 - (StartY + e.TotalY) / Height, 0, 1);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Status)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                LastScale = e.Scale;
                StartScale = Scale;
                AnchorX = e.ScaleOrigin.X;
                AnchorY = e.ScaleOrigin.Y;
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                if (e.Scale < 0 || Math.Abs(LastScale - e.Scale) > (LastScale * 1.3) - LastScale)
                { return; }
                LastScale = e.Scale;
                var current = Scale + (e.Scale - 1) * StartScale;
                Scale = Clamp(current, MIN_SCALE * (1 - OVERSHOOT), MAX_SCALE * (1 + OVERSHOOT));
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                if (Scale > MAX_SCALE)
                    this.ScaleTo(MAX_SCALE, 250, Easing.SpringOut);
                else if (Scale < MIN_SCALE)
                    this.ScaleTo(MIN_SCALE, 250, Easing.SpringOut);
                break;
        }
    }

    private T Clamp<T>(T value, T minimum, T maximum) where T : IComparable
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(minimum) < 0)
            return minimum;
        else if (value.CompareTo(maximum) > 0)
            return maximum;
        else
            return value;
    }
}
```

Good luck

Revert in case of queries.

Comment: Thank you for posting this, did you happen to improve on it? The zoom with pinch is choppy and jumps around, and the pan responds very slowly

Comment: @Derorrist Unfortunately I never really used it myself so I never improved on it, but if you have I'd love to hear about it

Comment: I did actually. I am working on a project that needs this functionality for dynamic maps. The code for one finger and two finger manipulation can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61657302/restrict-panning-of-skcanvasview-in-skiasharp/72546991#72546991