# Restrict panning of SKCanvasView in SkiaSharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, skiasharp

I'm making an image viewing feature in my app that allows the user to zoom and pan.

I've used the following documentation to achieve this through SkiaSharp.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/touch

What I am trying to achieve now is to restrict the user from zooming out or panning past the edges of the bitmap that is loaded into the SKCanvasView.

I have restricted the zoom but the problem I have is that I cannot figure out how to restrict the panning, I cannot find ANY example of how to do this online either. Is there a a SkiaSharp guru out there who has achieved this?

Here is code...

Relevant XAML:

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="#141d3d">
                <Grid.Effects>
                    <tt:TouchEffect Capture="True" TouchAction="OnTouchEffectAction" />
                </Grid.Effects>

                <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView" PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" />

                <Button Text="CLOSE"
                            TextColor="White"
                            VerticalOptions="Start"
                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            Command="{Binding CmdCloseFullImg}" />
            </Grid>
```

XAML.cs

```
public partial class AePage : ContentPage
    {
        private AeViewModel aeViewModel = new AeViewModel();

        private TouchManipulationBitmap bitmap = new TouchManipulationBitmap();
        private List<long> touchIds = new List<long>();

        public static float CanvasWidth { get; set; }
        public static float CanvasHeight { get; set; }

        public AePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = aeViewModel;
        }



        private void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
        {
            SKImageInfo info = e.Info;
            SKCanvas canvas = e.Surface.Canvas;
            canvas.Clear();

            // Display the bitmap
            bitmap.Paint(info, canvas);
        }

        private void OnTouchEffectAction(object sender, TouchActionEventArgs e)
        {
            CanvasWidth = canvasView.CanvasSize.Width;
            CanvasHeight = canvasView.CanvasSize.Height;

            // Convert Xamarin.Forms point to pixels
            TouchTrackingPoint pt = e.Location;
            SKPoint point = new SKPoint((float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width * pt.X / canvasView.Width),
                            (float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Height * pt.Y / canvasView.Height));
            switch (e.Type)
            {
                case TouchActionType.Pressed:
                    touchIds.Add(e.Id);
                    bitmap.ProcessTouchEvent(e.Id, e.Type, point);
                    break;

                case TouchActionType.Moved:
                    if (touchIds.Contains(e.Id))
                    {
                        bitmap.ProcessTouchEvent(e.Id, e.Type, point);
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                    break;

                case TouchActionType.Released:
                case TouchActionType.Cancelled:
                    if (touchIds.Contains(e.Id))
                    {
                        bitmap.ProcessTouchEvent(e.Id, e.Type, point);
                        touchIds.Remove(e.Id);
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

TouchManipulationBitmap Class:

```
public class TouchManipulationBitmap
    {
        public SKBitmap bitmap;

        public TouchManipulationManager TouchManager { set; get; }

        public static SKMatrix Matrix { set; get; }

        private Dictionary<long, TouchManipulationInfo> touchDictionary = new Dictionary<long, TouchManipulationInfo>();

        public TouchManipulationBitmap()
        {
            this.bitmap = ReturnSKBitmap();
            Matrix = SKMatrix.MakeIdentity();
            TouchManager = new TouchManipulationManager();
        }

        public SKBitmap ReturnSKBitmap()
        {
            string resourceId = "MetroAlarmHandlerMobile.Media.David DP.jpg";
            Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

            using (System.IO.Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceId))
            {
                return SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
            }
        }

        public void Paint(SKImageInfo info, SKCanvas canvas)
        {
            canvas.Save();
            SKMatrix matrix = Matrix;
            canvas.Concat(ref matrix);
            float scale = Math.Min((float)info.Width / bitmap.Width, (float)info.Height / bitmap.Height);

            float x = (info.Width - scale * bitmap.Width) / 2;
            float y = (info.Height - scale * bitmap.Height) / 2;

            SKRect destRect = new SKRect(x, y, x + scale * bitmap.Width, y + scale * bitmap.Height);
            canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, destRect);
            canvas.Restore();

            Console.WriteLine($"SCALE: {Matrix.ScaleX}");
            Console.WriteLine($"TRANSLATION: X = {Matrix.TransX} Y = {Matrix.TransY}");
        }

        public void ProcessTouchEvent(long id, TouchActionType type, SKPoint location)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case TouchActionType.Pressed:
                    touchDictionary.Add(id, new TouchManipulationInfo
                    {
                        PreviousPoint = location,
                        NewPoint = location
                    });
                    break;

                case TouchActionType.Moved:
                    TouchManipulationInfo info = touchDictionary[id];
                    info.NewPoint = location;
                    Manipulate();
                    info.PreviousPoint = info.NewPoint;
                    break;

                case TouchActionType.Released:
                    touchDictionary[id].NewPoint = location;
                    Manipulate();
                    touchDictionary.Remove(id);
                    break;

                case TouchActionType.Cancelled:
                    touchDictionary.Remove(id);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void Manipulate()
        {
            TouchManipulationInfo[] infos = new TouchManipulationInfo[touchDictionary.Count];
            touchDictionary.Values.CopyTo(infos, 0);
            SKMatrix touchMatrix = SKMatrix.MakeIdentity();

            if (infos.Length == 1)
            {
                SKPoint prevPoint = infos[0].PreviousPoint;
                SKPoint newPoint = infos[0].NewPoint;
                SKPoint pivotPoint = Matrix.MapPoint(bitmap.Width / 2, bitmap.Height / 2);

                touchMatrix = TouchManager.OneFingerManipulate(prevPoint, newPoint, pivotPoint);
            }
            else if (infos.Length >= 2)
            {
                int pivotIndex = infos[0].NewPoint == infos[0].PreviousPoint ? 0 : 1;
                SKPoint pivotPoint = infos[pivotIndex].NewPoint;
                SKPoint newPoint = infos[1 - pivotIndex].NewPoint;
                SKPoint prevPoint = infos[1 - pivotIndex].PreviousPoint;

                touchMatrix = TouchManager.TwoFingerManipulate(prevPoint, newPoint, pivotPoint);
            }

            SKMatrix matrix = Matrix;
            SKMatrix.PostConcat(ref matrix, touchMatrix);
            Matrix = matrix;
        }
    }
```

TouchManipulationManager Class:

```
public class TouchManipulationManager
    {
        private float Magnitude(SKPoint point)
        {
            return (float)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(point.X, 2) + Math.Pow(point.Y, 2));
        }

        public SKMatrix OneFingerManipulate(SKPoint prevPoint, SKPoint newPoint, SKPoint pivotPoint)
        {
            SKMatrix touchMatrix = SKMatrix.MakeIdentity();
            SKPoint delta = newPoint - prevPoint;


            // Multiply the rotation matrix by a translation matrix
            SKMatrix.PostConcat(ref touchMatrix, SKMatrix.MakeTranslation(delta.X, delta.Y));

            return touchMatrix;
        }

        public SKMatrix TwoFingerManipulate(SKPoint prevPoint, SKPoint newPoint, SKPoint pivotPoint)
        {
            SKMatrix touchMatrix = SKMatrix.MakeIdentity();
            SKPoint oldVector = prevPoint - pivotPoint;
            SKPoint newVector = newPoint - pivotPoint;

            float scale = Magnitude(newVector) / Magnitude(oldVector);

            if (TouchManipulationBitmap.Matrix.ScaleX <= 1 && scale <= 1) return touchMatrix;

            if (!float.IsNaN(scale) && !float.IsInfinity(scale))
            {
                SKMatrix.PostConcat(ref touchMatrix, SKMatrix.MakeScale(scale, scale, pivotPoint.X, pivotPoint.Y));
            }

            return touchMatrix;
        }
    }
```

TouchManipulationInfo Class:

```
public class TouchManipulationInfo
    {
        public SKPoint PreviousPoint { set; get; }

        public SKPoint NewPoint { set; get; }
    }
```

Comment: "restrict the panning" is pretty vague.  What specifically do you want to accomplish?  And it would help if you posted the relevant code, and not just link to some external site.

Comment: Thanks @Jason, have amended

Comment: can't you just check if the translation matrix exceeds the height or width of your bitmap, and skip it?  That's the approach that I would use

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still searching for the answer, this is what I came up with:

```
public TouchManipulationManager()
{
    bottomRight = new SKPoint(TouchManipulationBitmap.CanvasWidth, TouchManipulationBitmap.CanvasHeight);
}
```

Where `CanvasWidth` and `CanvasHeight` are static properties of `SKCanvasView.CanvasSize` (The element specified in the XAML file).
Make sure to grab them on `OnAppearing`, as they are both 0 in the view's c'tor.

For `OneFingerManipulate`, the idea is to find the relative top left and bottom right points of the original bitmap according to the current matrix (which may be scaled), and then see if the current movement request will cause the translation to exceed these bounds.

```
public SKMatrix OneFingerManipulate(SKPoint prevPoint, SKPoint newPoint)
    {
        // if movement will take us out of bounds of image, stop the movement in that direction
        SKPoint scaledBottomRight = TouchManipulationBitmap.Matrix.MapVector(bottomRight);
        
        SKPoint delta = newPoint - prevPoint;

        float translatedX = -TouchManipulationBitmap.Matrix.TransX + TouchManipulationBitmap.CanvasWidth;
        float translatedY = -TouchManipulationBitmap.Matrix.TransY + TouchManipulationBitmap.CanvasHeight;

        if ((delta.X > 0 && TouchManipulationBitmap.Matrix.TransX >= 0) // moving left
            ||
            (delta.X < 0 && translatedX >= scaledBottomRight.X)) // moving right
        {
            delta.X = 0;
        }

        if ((delta.Y > 0 && TouchManipulationBitmap.Matrix.TransY >= 0) // moving up
            ||
            (delta.Y < 0 && translatedY >= scaledBottomRight.Y)) // moving down
        {
            delta.Y = 0;
        }

        // multiply the rotation matrix by a translation matrix
        SKMatrix touchMatrix = SKMatrix.CreateIdentity();
        touchMatrix = touchMatrix.PostConcat(SKMatrix.CreateTranslation(delta.X, delta.Y));

        return touchMatrix;
    }
```

`TwoFingerManipulate` is a bit trickier, since the movement is on vectors. So I used a translation after the scaling

```
public SKMatrix TwoFingerManipulate(SKPoint prevPoint, SKPoint newPoint, SKPoint pivotPoint)
    {
        SKMatrix touchMatrix = SKMatrix.CreateIdentity();
        SKPoint oldVector = prevPoint - pivotPoint;
        SKPoint newVector = newPoint - pivotPoint;

        float scale = Magnitude(newVector) / Magnitude(oldVector);

        // if the scale crossed MIN_SCALE and the manipulation is below median (keep on scaling out) - do nothing
        if (TouchManipulationBitmap.Matrix.ScaleX <= TouchManipulationBitmap.SCALE_MIN && scale <= TouchManipulationBitmap.SCALE_MEDIAN) return touchMatrix;
        // if the scale crossed MAX_SCALE and the manipulation is above median (keep on scaling in) - do nothing
        if (TouchManipulationBitmap.Matrix.ScaleX >= TouchManipulationBitmap.SCALE_MAX && scale >= TouchManipulationBitmap.SCALE_MEDIAN) return touchMatrix;

        if (!float.IsNaN(scale) && !float.IsInfinity(scale))
        {
            touchMatrix = touchMatrix.PostConcat(SKMatrix.CreateScale(scale, scale, pivotPoint.X, pivotPoint.Y));
        }

        SKPoint topLeft = TouchManipulationBitmap.Matrix.MapPoint(new SKPoint(0, 0));
        SKPoint bottomRight = TouchManipulationBitmap.Matrix.MapPoint(new SKPoint(TouchManipulationBitmap.CanvasWidth, TouchManipulationBitmap.CanvasHeight));

        // top left
        if (topLeft.X > 0 && topLeft.Y > 0)
            touchMatrix = touchMatrix.PostConcat(SKMatrix.CreateTranslation(-topLeft.X, -topLeft.Y));
        // left
        else if (topLeft.X > 0)
            touchMatrix = touchMatrix.PostConcat(SKMatrix.CreateTranslation(-topLeft.X, 0));
        //top
        else if (topLeft.Y > 0)
            touchMatrix = touchMatrix.PostConcat(SKMatrix.CreateTranslation(0, -topLeft.Y));

        // bottom right
        if (bottomRight.X < TouchManipulationBitmap.CanvasWidth && bottomRight.Y < TouchManipulationBitmap.CanvasHeight)
            touchMatrix = touchMatrix.PostConcat(SKMatrix.CreateTranslation(TouchManipulationBitmap.CanvasWidth - bottomRight.X, TouchManipulationBitmap.CanvasHeight - bottomRight.Y));
        // right
        else if (bottomRight.X < TouchManipulationBitmap.CanvasWidth)
            touchMatrix = touchMatrix.PostConcat(SKMatrix.CreateTranslation(TouchManipulationBitmap.CanvasWidth - bottomRight.X, 0));
        // bottom
        else if (bottomRight.Y < TouchManipulationBitmap.CanvasHeight)
            touchMatrix = touchMatrix.PostConcat(SKMatrix.CreateTranslation(0, TouchManipulationBitmap.CanvasHeight - bottomRight.Y));

        return touchMatrix;
    }
```

Comment: This might be asking for too much, but I have a Github OSS library and I am thinking I will add a Zoomable Image kind of functionality as a control there, I was hoping you could help me either understand your code here or if you could guide me to somewhere I can find the full code and study it for my control!!

Comment: @FreakyAli I uploaded a skeletal code to https://github.com/drormekorot/ZoomableImage. I had to remove some proprietary code so this will not work out of the box, but I'm sure will save you a lot of time I spent on it. It has some nice features such as hotspots, double-tap zoom, auto-zoom on hotspot click, hiding overlay buttons on zoom, stuff like that. If you have any questions feel free to contact me, I'll try my best to help you out

Comment: I really appreciate your help here, Thanks a lot, I will link the control when I create it for MAUI here hopefully it will help you in the future :)