# Adding Xamarin GestureRecognizers on SKCanvasView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I have added Xamarin GestureRecognizers on a SKCanvasView and overridden OnTouch method.
I have some implementations on SKTouchAction.Moved. In order to trigger it after SKTouchAction.Pressed on Android I set e.Handled = true;
Doing so, none of the Xamarin GestureRecognizers seems to be working.
Is there any way to make both of these events work together or any alternative way to achieve this requirement?

Here is my code sample.

```
 public abstract class GestureContainer : SKCanvasView, IViewportable
 {
    public GestureContainer()
    {
            var doubleTapGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            doubleTapGesture.NumberOfTapsRequired = 2;
            doubleTapGesture.Tapped += TapGesture_DoubleTapped;
            GestureRecognizers.Add(doubleTapGesture);

            var pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
            pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
            GestureRecognizers.Add(pinchGesture);
    }

    private void TapGesture_DoubleTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Double tap action here
    }

    public void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Pinch action here
    }

    protected override void OnTouch(SKTouchEventArgs e)
    { 
        switch (e.ActionType)
        {
             case SKTouchAction.Moved:
             {
                //Move action here
             }
             break;
             case SKTouchAction.Pressed:
             {
                //Move action here
             }
             break;
        }
         e.Handled = false; // Xamarin gesture works when I set this to false
        InvalidateSurface();
    }

 }
```

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @ewerspej - they want to use skia's touch events, and xamarin forms TapGestureRecognizer, on the same element (the skia canvas view). When they attempt to do so, xamarin forms does not see the touch; skia element "swallows" it.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes, that part I get, but why? What's the reason for doing this? SKCanvasView can accept touch events without the need for a GestureRecognizer. What am I missing?

Comment: I see your point. Question shows pinch and double-tap. What exactly does Skia offer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55497649/199364 might be relevant.

Comment: I found this issue opened here: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/909
For those willing pan/pinch gesture with skia, better set e.Handled = false, and only play with Xamarin gestures.